# flutter Using flutter csv package with rootBundle

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to load a csv file from assets folder which is set correctly in YAML file using csv package, but i am getting this error.

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'String?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable The instance member
> 'csvFile' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the
> reference to the instance member with a different expression

I am aware that CsvToListConverter takes a string as an argument instead of `Future<String>.`

```
  final csvFile = rootBundle.loadString('assets/csv_file.txt');
  final csvToLIst = CsvToListConverter(eol: '\n\r', fieldDelimiter: '\t')
  .convert(csvFile);
```

I was able read the csv file with File from dart:io. But when I build the app It kinda looses the relative path to the csv file. That's the whole point to use rootBundle I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rootBundle.loadString returns a Future, so you must await it:

you should wrap your function with async first and add await in the future returning method

```
  getWorkDone() async{
    final csvFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/csv_file.txt');
    final csvToLIst = CsvToListConverter(eol: '\n\r', fieldDelimiter: '\t')
        .convert(csvFile);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`AssetBundle#loadString`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html) returns a `Future<String>`, so you must `await` it:

```dart
final csvFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/csv_file.txt');
final csvToLIst = CsvToListConverter(eol: '\n\r', fieldDelimiter: '\t').convert(csvFile);
```

Note that `await` must only be called in an `async` environment. You can read more [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).